# Need help in configuring log format for Jboss 6.4

Tags: linux, logging, jboss

I am trying to configure my Jboss logs in the following format in Jboss 6.4

```
<DATE> <TIME> <LEVEL> [<CLASS>] (<THREAD>) MESSAGE

*Example*
2017-03-09 05:09:05,961 INFO  [com.app.checker.CallInterceptor] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:22329-5 api~55C41D7CDD44XXXX646.api GET /call/get) processing the request
```

My current logger properties file have the following entry

```
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```

Please suggest following edits in above entry to match the required log format above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to [`log4j` synthax](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

- `%-5p` for level
- `%t` for thread
- `%c` for class
- `%M` is for function where issue originates
- `%L` is the line

This pattern `%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c.%M:%L] (%t) %s%E%n` works for me:

```
12:19:06,131 DEBUG [test.testConfig:731] (main) Test message to show up on the console.
```

Then to add the date with time zone if you want:

`%d{yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss,SSS Z} %-5p [%c.%M:%L] (%t) %s%E%n`